# Наследование данных в if

Tags: python, ооп, наследование, if

Почему при инпуте цифры 1 - super().gamer_input_x() в условии if не равен 1? Питон выдает 1 != 1
Спасибо заранее

```
class Gamer:
    def __init__(self):
        self.gamer_x = 0

    def gamer_input_x(self):
        self.gamer_x = input("Введите позицию Х: ")
        return self.gamer_x

class Gamer_check(Gamer):
    def gamer_check(self):
        if super().gamer_input_x() == 1:
            print(self.gamer_x, ' =1')
        else:
            print(self.gamer_x, ' !=1')

test = Gamer_check()
test.gamer_check()
```

Comment: Потому что input всегда возвращает строку, строка "1" не равна числу 1.

Answer (score 1):

`input` возвращает строку, а вы сравниваете с числом.

Исправить можно так:

```
self.gamer_x = int(input("...."))
```